# Wordpress API works with VPN only?

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm working on a project on my localhost for sometime now, and i've recently tried to make it online. My project works perfectly on my localhost, and I can post new articles to wordpress blogs with no problem.

The problem is, after uploading my project to a online web server ( Hostgators Baby Plan ) , I tried to add a new post to one of my wordpress blogs and I got the following error :

```
faultCode 500 faultString You are not allowed to do that.
```

The thing is, I've searched everywhere in the past few days in-order to solve this problem and had no luck.

Do you guys think this problem is caused because i'm using a webserver and not a VPS? If you have any other solutions I'll be glad to hear them out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to file permissions or something like that.
There is no need to use VPS. I manage my website on a shared server and I've tested WordPress on free hosting services too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to incorrect permissions either on the file structure or the mySQL DB user or something like that.  Take a look at [this article on the WP codex about file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

Big services like Hostgater usually have an "auto-install" feature for common software like Wordpress (via Softaculous or something similar).  I don't know how you migrated your site from your local version to the server but it may be worth installing a fresh Wordpress instance through Hostgator and then simply loading in the wp-content folder and your development database on top of that.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I'm trying to add a post through my website (Example : demo.myweb.com) to a free wordpress blog ( Example : mywebsite.wordpress.com ). They are not on the same server.

Comment: Bumping.. Any ideas anyone?